# What is the right syntax for tableView functions in Swift 3? xCode 8 issues

Tags: macos, nstableview, swift3, xcode8

I have just upgraded to xCode Version 8.0 (8A218a). I have been trying to convert some older code to Swift 3.0 and I am struggling to understand how to fix some issues with a tableView and I am confused by the documentation and some errors I am getting.

I am getting this error

> *** Illegal NSTableView data source ().  Must implement numberOfRowsInTableView: and
>   tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:

When running this code:

```
class listMusicEvents: ViewController, performanceDataModelDelegate, NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource {

let eventModel = performanceDataModel.sharedInstance
var musicEvents:[performanceEvent] = []


@IBOutlet var tableView: NSTableView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    eventModel.delegate = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    eventModel.getPerformanceEvents()
}

func performanceEventsLoaded() {

    musicEvents = eventModel.eventList
    print(musicEvents[0].eventTitle)
}

func performanceSaveError(headline: String, message: String, error: NSError) {
    print(error)
}

func numberOfRowsInTableView( in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
    return musicEvents.count
}

func tableView(_tableView:NSTableView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> AnyObject{

    if tableColumn?.title == "Date" {
        let date = musicEvents[row].eventDate
        return date as AnyObject

    } else {

        let title = musicEvents[row].eventTitle
        return title as AnyObject
    }

}
```

}

I thought I had implemented the new methods, but it looks like I am not understanding something basic.

I am getting a warning on the objectValueFor function:

> Instance method 'tableView(*tableView:objectValueForRow:row:)' nearly
>   matches optional requirement 'tableView(*:setObjectValue:for:row:) of
>   protocol 'NSTableViewDataSource'

I've looked at the delegate docs and they say setObjectValue should not be used for a view-based tableView, which is what I have (I think).

The code I was using originally for the table column was:

```
tableView(tableView: NSTableView, objectValueForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> AnyObject? { . . .
```

This line worked fine before brining the project into xCode 8

Can someone please explain how view-based tableViews are supposed to work with Swift 3 and what I am getting wrong? Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: Just let Xcode auto complete it for you. Try Any instead of AnyObject

Comment: I have tired letting auto completion work. I can get rid of the warning the version xCode likes is: `tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> Any?` Yet I am still getting the Illegal data source error. I have carefully checked the Connections inspector, cleaned the project, etc.

Comment: I have checked it on a real project 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/88zszm4byjqvzld/Screen%20Shot%202016-09-30%20at%2010.51.57%20AM.png?dl=0
So you can see there is no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restarting my computer eliminated the Illegal NSTableView data source. I guess xCode 8 worked itself into a state where it could not let go of the error.

The objectValueFor function provided by auto complete was the correct one.

Comment: I hate these random issues that only thing, how to solve them is restart your Mac :-D

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem as follows.
Add ***NSTableViewDataSource*** protocol to the ViewController class.

```
class ViewController: NSViewController,NSTableViewDataSource{

    // snip //

    func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {        

      // snip //

      return count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> Any?{

      // snip //

      return element
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update for Swift 3**

I had to use the following prototypes...auto-complete is your friend:

```
func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int
```

and

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView?
```